# Problem with registering multiple instances of Zuul with Eureka. Port gets registerd as 0

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am using Zuul with Spring Boot. As I understand, in order to run multiple instances of the same application, the port number should be specified as `0` in application.yml. This way the app starts running on a random available port at startup.

I have done the same for Zuul Server app. When I start two instances of Zuul Server, both start running on random ports as expected. However the **Eureka registry does not record their ports correctly. It records port number as 0.**

I have used port as 0 in application.yml for my endpoint Spring Boot apps as well. Eureka has no problems registering the correct port for each endpoint instance. It is only with the Zuul Server app that the port gets registered as `0`.

application.yml for the Zuul Server app

```
server:
  host: localhost
  port: 0

zuul:
  routes:
    foos:
      path: /api/**
      serviceId: endpoint

spring:
   application:
      name: zuul-server

eureka:
   client:
      registerWithEureka: true
      fetchRegistry: true
      serviceUrl:
         defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
   instance: 
      preferIpAddress: true
      instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}



management:
   endpoints:
      web:
         exposure:
            include: "routes,beans"
```

I am using Zuul 1.3.1, Spring Boot 2.1.8, Spring Cloud Version: Greenwich.SR3

POM For Eureka Server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.priyank</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>eureka</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
        <!-- <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version> -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>       
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

POM for Zuul Server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.billdesk.priyank</groupId>
    <artifactId>zuul</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>zuul</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Did you get solution to this question

Comment: No, we moved on with Kubernetes, which makes Zuul/Eureka irrelevant. That is the way to go for scaling microservices.